# Why does timestamp differ?

Tags: javascript, json, date

I was given a JSON file with timestamps.

One of them is: `1545880457898`

I was able to get the actual date by doing:
`new Date(ticket.creationTime).toLocaleString()`, and it gave me: `27/12/2018, 04:14:17`.

Now, I tried converting the date: `27/12/2018` by doing:
`new Date(Number(split[2]),Number(split[1]),Number(split[0])).getTime()`, and got: `1548543600000`.

Which is very different, and especially very larger. This is a huge problem since I'm comparing them to sort them by creation time.

Anyone knows why do they differ? And how can I get the equivalent of case1?

Comment: But your original timestamp isn't correct: `1542111235544` gives you `11/13/2018` not `27/12/2018`. Also remember that the [`Date()` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#Individual_date_and_time_component_values) explicity states that the month uses `monthIndex` (i.e. zero-based), so that might be why your month came out incorrect.

Comment: Sorry an oversight. Edited the question

Comment: There is no need convert to number using `(Number(split[2])`, etc. You can just do `new Date(split[2], split[1] - 1, split[0]).getTime()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because Date api takes month as number starting from 0, in this case it needs to be 11 instead of 12

```
new Date(Number(split[2]),Number(split[1]) - 1,Number(split[0])).getTime()
```

But it also won't give exact 1545880457898, because we are not providing time to Date api

Comment: Thank you, solved my problem. Didn't mind if they were identical, I just needed them to be chronological and it worked

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues with your code:

1. You are converting a timestamp that contains hours, minutes and seconds information into one that only uses year, month, and day. Therefore you cannot reconstitute the original timestamp since you're discarding hours/minutes/seconds information.
2. Your output is in the format of `MM/DD/YYYY` (but that depends on your locale), but when split it up and supply it to the `new Date()` constructor, you are mixing up the order of the positional arguments.
3. The `new Date()` constructor uses zero-based `monthIndex`, so you need to minus 1 from the month you've gotten from the string.

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
const creationTime = 1545880457898;

const dateString = new Date(creationTime).toLocaleString();

const split = dateString.split(',')[0].split('/')

const newTime = new Date(Number(split[2]),Number(split[0]) - 1,Number(split[1])).getTime();
console.log(newTime);
```

However, the `.toLocaleString()` will produce an output that is **not consistent** (because it is locale-dependent), and I **strongly advise parsing a unix timestamp to string and then back again**. You should always use the unix timestamp as a source of truth instead. The `toLocaleString()` should preferably be used for one-way data presentation (i.e. displaying the date) and you should not use it to "reconstruct" the original timestamp.

Comment: in the code second position need to be month, by mistaken you put date there

Comment: It depends on the locale you’re at. For me: month was the first item in the array.

Comment: Re "*Your output is in the format of MM/DD/YYYY*", no it isn't, "27/12/2018" is in d/m/y format.

Comment: As I’ve mentioned exhaustively multiple times at this point: the order is not guaranteed as it is locale dependent. What I got on my end was indeed MM/DD/YYYY.